# AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'delayed'

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

Using Pycharm Community 2018.1.4
Python 3.6
Dask 2.8.1

Trying to implement dask delayed on some of my methods and getting an error

```
AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'delayed'.
```

This is obviously not true so I am wondering what I am doing wrong. My implementation structure is as follows:

```py
import dask
def main()
  for i, fn in enumarate(filenames):
     data = {}
     for x in range(0,2):
         data.update(dask.delayed(load_data)(fn, x))
         succes_flag = dask.delayed(execute_analytic)(data)

         if success_flag == 1:
            print("success")
         else:
            print("fail")

def load_data(filename,selector):

def execute_analytic(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dask.compute(main())
```

Essentialy, I have a bunch of data files, which are independant of each other and so I want to run them in parallel instead of sequentially through a for loop, which i was doing if you take the dask.delayed out.
Am i fundamentally missing anything in the above implementation of dask delayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I refer the following URL https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1849

To install Dask with pip there are a few options, depending on which
dependencies you would like to keep up to date:

- pip install dask[complete]: Install everything
- pip install dask[array]: Install dask and numpy
- pip install dask[bag]: Install dask and cloudpickle
- pip install dask[dataframe]: Install dask, numpy, and pandas
- pip install dask: Install only dask, which depends only on the standard
  library. This is appropriate if you only want the task schedulers.

Comment: Thank you this was NIGHTMARISHLY frustrating. Commenting to tag for anyone searching solve on other dask module errors:

module 'dask' has no attribute 'set_options'

Answer (score 3):

You probably only installed the core library, rather than the full library with normal dependencies.

```
conda install dask
or
pip install dask[complete]
```

See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/install.html for more information

Comment: `pip install "dask[complete]"` you need to add quotes

Answer (score 1):

`pip install "dask[delayed]"` is the minimal requirement to directly answer the OP (the other answers may install unnecessary dependencies)